# (qt) How to make scroll bar height constant in qml

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to make hight of scrollbar constant, irrespective of number of elements in listview. But I didn't find any property to do this. Please suggest how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Code snippet :

```
Listview {
    id:mylistview
    height :400
    Width:500
    ScrollBar.vertical: scbr
    model :mymodel
    delegate:del{} 
} 

ScrollBar
{ 
    id: scbr 
    active: true
    interactive : true 
    hoverEnabled: true
    orientation :Qt.vertical 
    snapMode : ScrollBar.NoSnap
    contentItem: 
        Rectangle {  
        implicitWidth: 60                           
        implicitHeight: 100
        color: "#ff0000" 
    }
}
```

Here even we set implicitWidth is 60. But when model having very huge data, Scroll bar image changes it's height to very small.

Comment: The height of the scrollbar does not depend on the model but on the height of the container, if you want it to not vary the size of your container. As I do not show any code you can not give an answer.

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47310544/edit) and place your code there.

Comment: In above code snippet is it possible to make scroll bar height constant?

Comment: Various. You could use a `Slider` and bind its value to the `ListView`-position. You can also wrap the visible `Rectangle` in an invisible `Item`. Then the `Item`'s size will change, but not so the `Rectangle`. You will need to deal with the right position of the `Rectangle` inside the `Item`. The size will only *visually* change. The area reactive to the mouse wont change by that.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a scrollbar which is more a **scroll indicator** as it does not control the view. It can be positioned in a way that indicates your views current position in relative to the full content.

Lets consider a list with a delegate of height "h". You can create a rectangle with a desired height and width (say a height of 100 and width of 60 as in your example).

The x coordinate -> width of list - width of scroll indicator(60 in this case)

y coordinate would be the relative property which would be 
(list.contentY * (list.height-indicator.height)) / (list.height - delegate.height)

A sample is as below:

```
Rectangle {
             id: indicator
             x: 0
             y: ((list.contentY) * (list.height - indicator.height)) / (list.height - delegate.height)
             width: 10
             height: 150
             color: "blue"
             radius: 10
         }
```

where list is the id of your list and delegate is the id of delegate in your view.

I am not sure whether it would suit your exact purpose but I had to move along in this way for a similar requirement for keeping a fixed size scrollbar.